# Why does my code only not print anything other than 3 or 7?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a craps game in which if the computer automatically a pair of dice and if the cpu rolls a 7 or 11 the user win. However if the user rolls a 2, 3, or 12 they automatically lose. And if the user rolls any other number (4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10) that is there "point" and they are to try to roll that point again. (unless they roll a 7 then they lose.) I am trying to get my while loop to continue rolling if the computer rolls a number other than 7 or the "point" the only thing that runs is "congrats you rolled a 7 you've won" or "you've rolled a 3 you've love"

this is what i have now..

```
public class CrapsPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int d1 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        int d2 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        int roll = (d1 + d2);
        int point = roll;

        if (roll == 7 || roll == 11)

        {
            System.out.println("You rolled a" + roll);
            System.out.println("Congrats! You've immediately won!");

        }

        else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12) {
            System.out.println("you rolled a " + roll);
            System.out.println("You lose!");

            while (roll != 7 && roll != point) {
                int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
                int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
                roll = d3 + d4;

                System.out.println("your point is" + point);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Check your curly braces

Answer (score 1):

You're curly braces are incorrectly placed. You're closing you're `else if` after your `while` has started. You should reformat to something like this:

```
public class crapsPractice{
public static void main(String[]args){   


   int d1 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
   int d2 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
   int roll = (d1 + d2);
   int point = roll; 




       if (roll == 7 || roll == 11) 

       {
         System.out.println("You rolled a" + roll); 
         System.out.println("Congrats! You've immediately won!");

       }

       else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
       {
         System.out.println("you rolled a " + roll);
         System.out.println("You lose!");
       }

    while(roll != 7 && roll != point )
    {
    int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
    roll = d3 + d4;

    System.out.println("your point is" + point);

    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

NotZack is right check your brackets, but also you have this:

`while(roll != 7 && roll != point )`

Doesn't `roll` and `point` equal the same, so it'll never run your while loop

Comment: How would I implement a do while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the else part and that is why is not printing other numbers.
Also Class name always start with **Capital** letter.

```
public class CrapsPractice {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int d1 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
            int d2 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
            int roll = (d1 + d2);
            int point = roll;

            if (roll == 7 || roll == 11)

            {
                System.out.println("You rolled a" + roll);
                System.out.println("Congrats! You've immediately won!");

            }

            else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12) {
                System.out.println("you rolled a " + roll);
                System.out.println("You lose!");

                while (roll != 7 && roll != point) {
                    int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
                    int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
                    roll = d3 + d4;

                    System.out.println("your point is" + point);

                }
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("your point is " + point);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As many comments/answers pointed out, you definitely have a curly braces here.

Plus, when the user immediately won or lost, I assume you want to stop execution, and not enter the while loop. To do so, either surround the loop by `else` block, or use a `return;` statement to terminate the program.

**Edit:** Also, as others pointed out, your while condition (`roll != 7 && roll != point`) **is never satisfied**, as roll is still `equal` to `point` at this stage. You can fix that by either *re-setting the value of `roll` to a default value* (e.g. 0), or *using a do-while loop*.

Using a do-while loop, the loop's body will always execute once before checking against the condition.

```
public class CrapsPractice{
    public static void main(String[]args){   


        int d1 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        int d2 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        int roll = (d1 + d2);
        int point = roll; 




        if (roll == 7 || roll == 11) 

        {
          System.out.println("You rolled a" + roll); 
          System.out.println("Congrats! You've immediately won!");
          return; //terminate the main function

        }

        else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
        {
          System.out.println("you rolled a " + roll);
          System.out.println("You lose!");
          return; //terminate the main function

        }

        //do-while loop: execute and then check for condition
        //and then if condition holds, execute a second time and so on
        do {
            int d3 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
            int d4 = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
            roll = d3 + d4;

            System.out.println("your point is" + point);

        } while(roll != 7 && roll != point );
    }
}
```

On a side note, it seems you are always printing the same thing in your while loop, did you mean to print `roll` instead of `point`?

Comment: after executing the code it is still only printing the point once as opposed until continuing to roll until it hits the point again and printing out said rolls.